# Is there any way to display title when redirect a url in VUE JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Currently , i have a navigation drawer component. So the idea is like this , when user navigate to any navigation such as home page or profile page , the title will change accordingly based on the route. For example , if the user navigate to home page `(e.g. "/")` , the title will change to "Home" and if the user navigate to profile page `(e.g. /profile)` , the title will change to "Profile". However , if I accessed any of URLs directly `e.g /profile , /profile/list`, the title would not change to "Profile" instead the title will use the default value which is "TEST". Should I implement a `watch` method on my route to solve this problem ?

`index.js`

```
export const state = () => ({
  title: 'TEST',
})

export const getters = {
  getTitle: (state) => state.title
}

export const mutations = {
  setTitle(state, value) {
    state.title = value
  }
}

export const actions = {
  setTitle({ commit }, value) {
    commit('setTitle', value)
  }
}
```

`NavigationDrawer.vue`

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    drawer: true,
    items: [
      {
        icon: 'mdi-home',
        title: 'Home',
        to: '/'
      },
      {
        icon: 'mdi-account',
        title: 'Profile',
        style: 'profile',
        links: [
          { title: 'Dashbord', to: '/profile/' },
          { title: 'Staff List', to: '/profile/list' },
          { title: 'Search', to: '/profile/search' },
        ]
      },
      {
        icon: 'mdi-umbrella-beach',
        title: 'E-Leave',
        style: 'leave',
        to: '/leave',
      },
      {
        icon: 'mdi-calendar-clock',
        title: 'Time Attendance',
        style: 'attendance',
        to: '/attendance'
      },
      {
        icon: 'mdi-car-lifted-pickup',
        title: 'Reservation',
        style: 'reservation',
        to: '/reservation'
      },
      {
        icon: 'mdi-weight-lifter',
        title: 'Staff Training',
        style: 'training',
        links: [
          { title: 'Training Records', to: '/training/records' },
          { title: 'Training Programs', to: '/training/programs' },
        ]
      },
      {
        icon: 'mdi-medical-bag',
        title: 'Medical',
        style: 'medical',
        links: [
          { title: 'My Balances', to: '/medical/balance/self' },
        ]
      },
    ],
  }),

  methods: {
  getCurrentPageNameByPath(){
      var array = [
          { name:"Profile", value:"/profile/"},
      ];
      const search = what => array.find(element => element.name === what);
      const found = search("Profile");
      if (found) {
          console.log(found.value, found.other);
      } else {
          console.log('No result found');
      }
    },
    updatePageTitle(title) {
      this.$store.dispatch('setTitle', title)
    },
    toggleDrawer() {
      this.drawer = !this.drawer;
    },
    isAdminChipVisible(link) {
        return (link.hasOwnProperty('is_hr') && link.is_hr) || (link.hasOwnProperty('is_hod') && link.is_hod);
    },
    isVisibleForRegularUser(link, item) {
      return item.public || ( this.$auth.user && (!link.hasOwnProperty('is_hod') || link.is_hod == false)  && (!link.hasOwnProperty('is_hr') || link.is_hr == false) );
    },
    isVisibleForHod(link, item) {
      return item.public || ( this.$auth.user && (link.hasOwnProperty('is_hod') && link.is_hod) && this.$auth.user.is_hod );
    },
    isVisibleForHrAdmin(link, item) {
      return item.public || ( this.$auth.user && (link.hasOwnProperty('is_hr') && link.is_hr) && this.$auth.user.is_hr_admin );
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    const currentPath = this.$router.currentRoute.path
   const currentPageName = this.getCurrentPageNameByPath(currentPath)

   this.$store.dispatch("setTitle",currentPageName)
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      if (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown) this.drawer = false
    })

  },
}
</script>

<template class="nav-color-gradient">
  <v-navigation-drawer
    class="nav-color-gradient"
    v-model="drawer"
    :width="300"
    app
    dark
    fixed
    floating
  >
    <template v-slot:prepend>
      <div class="navigation-drawer__spacer">
        <div class="text-center my-5">
        <img src="/snet_white.png" height="50" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:append>
      <div class="navigation-drawer__spacer"></div>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:default>
      <v-list class="py-0">
        <template
          v-for="(item, index) in items"
        >
          <v-list-group
            v-if="item.links"
            :append-icon="null"
            :group="item.to"
            :ripple="false"
            v-bind:key="index"
            router
          >
            <template v-slot:activator>
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title
                  class="text-right"
                  v-text="item.title.toUpperCase()"
                >
                </v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </template>

            <template v-for="(link, l) in item.links">

              <!-- for hod -->
              <v-list-item
                v-if="isVisibleForHod(link, item)"
                :key="l"
                :class="item.style"
                :ripple="false"
                :to="link.to"
                exact
                router
                @click="updatePageTitle([item.title, link.title])"
              >
                <v-list-item-title class="text-right">
                  <v-chip v-if="isAdminChipVisible(link)" color="white float-left" x-small>ADMIN</v-chip>
                  {{link.title.toUpperCase()}}
                </v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>


              <!-- for hr admin -->
              <v-list-item
                v-else-if="isVisibleForHrAdmin(link, item)"
                :key="l"
                :class="item.style"
                :ripple="false"
                :to="link.to"
                exact
                router
                @click="updatePageTitle([item.title, link.title])"
              >
                <v-list-item-title class="text-right">
                  <v-chip v-if="isAdminChipVisible(link)" color="white float-left" x-small>ADMIN</v-chip>
                  {{link.title.toUpperCase()}}
                </v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>

              <!-- for regular staff -->
              <v-list-item v-else-if="isVisibleForRegularUser(link, item)"
                :key="l"
                :class="item.style"
                :ripple="false"
                :to="link.to"
                exact
                router
                @click="updatePageTitle([item.title, link.title])"
              >
                <v-list-item-title class="text-right">
                  {{link.title.toUpperCase()}}
                </v-list-item-title>
              </v-list-item>

            </template>
          </v-list-group>

          <v-list-item
            exact-active-class="primary--text"
            :ripple="false"
            :to="item.to"
            v-bind:key="index"
            exact
            router
            v-else
            @click="updatePageTitle(item.title)"
          >
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title
                class="text-right"
                v-text="item.title.toUpperCase()"
              >
              </v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-action>
              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-action>
          </v-list-item>
        </template>
      </v-list>
    </template>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose for you two ways to do this :

1 - You can dispatch 'setTitle' action on mounted of each page. For example on Profile.vue page you should add this code :

```js
mounted(){
    // Current page Name is the page Name, in this case it's Profile
    this.$store.dispatch("setTitle",currentPageName)
}
```

2 - You can extract the page name from the current route url in 'created' or 'mounted' method of the 'NavigationDrawer.vue' file, then dispatch new Action 'setTitle' by passing the page name :

```js
mounted(){
   // your code 
   ......
   // 1 - Get current path from router
   const currentPath = this.$router.currentRoute.path
   // 2 - Search for page Name in items array , you can create a method
   // (getCurrentPageNameByPath) for doing this task
   const currentPageName = getCurrentPageNameByPath(currentPath)
   // 3 - dispatch cureent page name
   this.$store.dispatch("setTitle",currentPageName)
}

methods : {
   getCurrentPageNameByPath(path){
      let path = '/profile/'
      let currentPageName = ''

      for(let item of items){
         if(item.links) {
             for(let nestdItem of item.links ){
                 if(nestdItem.to == path) {
                    currentPageName = item.title;
                    break;
                 }
            }  
         }else {
              if(item.to == path) {
              currentPageName = item.title;
              break;
         }
       }
     }

     console.log(currentPageName)
     return currentPageName
   }

}
```

Comment: the 1st propose was good , but i would like to try the 2nd propose. Do i have to define the `getCurrentPageNameByPath` function first?

Comment: Yeah you should create a method that does the work for you, the main feature that gives this method is to find pageName by passing pagePath, or you can for example define an object that contains key as pagePaths and value as pageNames like that : 
{
"/profile":"Profile",
....
}
to make search more simple for you

Comment: i just updated the code but i think i did not iterate the keys and values ,  could u give me some feedback on it

Comment: Yeah it's look right, but for nested properties it's difficult to get the corresponding title, for example /profile/list, that's why the method should search in 2 levels , you can look at my response i 'll update it

Comment: seems abit complicated , i will try digest it awhile. if the 2nd propose cant be use , i will just implement the 1st propose

Answer (score 0):

You can use the beforeRouteEnter hook,

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
// document.title = to.title; // Optional set page title from here as well 
store.dispatch("setTitle",to.title);
next();
```

}

You have to import store because you can't access $store inside the router hook

Comment: Do i put this under method section in `NavigationDrawer.vue` ?

Comment: You can add this to any  vue page (vue component ), but beforeRouterEnter for the specific page will detect routerEnter only for that file, so I suggest you can add this to a  router file (something like router.js), that has all routing, mode etc configuration 

this will work for all routes in your app